# background-image in hover doesn't works properly

Tags: css, hover, border-image

I am trying to add a hover effect which adds background-image when a user hovers on the button but on hover there is a little area left on the left side which is still transparent.

Basically, I added two buttons, next to each other and the problem is with the 2nd button, if I remove first one or move 2nd to next line then it works totally fine.

Here is what am I getting.
[image: Not Working]

Here is how it looks if I remove the first button 
[image: Working Image]

Here is the code

```css
.gradient-button-1 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.gradient-button-1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    color: white;
}

.gradient-button-2 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.gradient-button-2:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-right: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<section>

          <h4>Gradient Bordered Buttons</h4>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-1">Gradient button 1</button>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-2">Gradient button 2</button>

        </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some screen sizes, background is not starting from the left most; which is why it leaves a small gap (white line).

You can add `background-origin: border-box;` to `.gradient-button-2:hover`. A good explanation and a live example can be found here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin):

> The `background-origin` CSS property sets the *background positioning area*. In other words, it sets the origin position of an image set with the `background-image` property.

```css
.gradient-button-1 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.gradient-button-1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    color: white;
}

.gradient-button-2 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.gradient-button-2:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-right: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    color: white;
    background-origin: border-box; /* This line is new! */
}
```

```html
<section>

          <h4>Gradient Bordered Buttons</h4>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-1">Gradient button 1</button>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-2">Gradient button 2</button>

        </section>
```

Comment: better use MDN as the reference not w3schools : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right, I updated the answer with MDN reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gradient-button-1 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.gradient-button-1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, orangered,yellow);
    color: white;
     background-position: -1px;
    background-size: 101%;
}

.gradient-button-2 {
    color: orangered;
    background: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    outline: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    
     
     
}
.gradient-button-2:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orangered,transparent);
    border-right: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    color: white;
    
  
    
}
```

```html
<section>

          <h4>Gradient Bordered Buttons</h4>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-1">Gradient button 1</button>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="gradient-button-2">Gradient button 2</button>

        </section>
```

Comment: add below css to button1:hover :   background-position: -1px;
    background-size: 101%;